# d-none g-3 display none and Gutter Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am new on bootsrtap using latest version
by using d-none on small device it still showing on sm While hide on lg and md

Q2 Gutter Size not Working In row in grid system

try many time but i failed finding solution for this

Comment: You would probably get a better response to your question if you supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way we can see what the problem in your code is, instead of just guessing what you did.